# DevOps - Self-Service Portal for developers and testers

Tags: asp.net, powershell, portal

Goal: 
Offload Operations team and let devs and QA teams to execute basic tasks such as :
- reset IIS
- compare folders on two servers (to make sure that released build is sync'ed on load-balanced servers)
- some other basic tasks

for all these tasks, Ops team has PowerShell scripts

Question:
<strike>Is there an open-source or commercial solution that would allow Ops team to integrate PowerShell scripts in a UI which will be used by devs and testers?</strike>

The only option I was able to find is to create ASP.NET web app and use .NET to execute powershell scripts. It will work, but it requires a developer to create and maintain that app.

How can I let developers and testers to execute PowerShell scripts without giving them permissions to resources that will be accessed by these PowerShell scripts?

Comment: [Recommendation Questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139399/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: hmm...ok, instead of "what software should I use", can I rephrase the question and ask "How do I allow developers and testers" to execute PowerShell scripts without giving them permissions which would required to access servers these scripts will be pulling information from or restarting IIS?

Answer (score 0):

You could give them access to a constrained remoting endpoint which runs as a user that has access to the resources in question.  You can control which functions (or cmdlets, scripts, etc.) are available to the session.